# wso2 version 1.1 upgrade to 4.0.1 data services fail

Tags: oracle, service, wso2

Recently upgraded our wso2 1.1 to 4.0.1 All Data Services functions now fail with INCOMPATIBLE_PARAMETERS_ERROR ? All works fine in 1.1. All functions use Oracle thin client driver.

Any suggestions? I have taken a look around input parameters but nothing appears to be obvious. I have also noticed when 'try this service' is used the screen layout is different. Version 1.1 had a panel for input values, 4.0.1 looks somewhat different.....?

Comment: If you can post one of your data services configurations, it would be more helpful to identify your issue.